# Multiple Cast from DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm having a bit of problem with casting and datagrids. I have a LINQ to SQL query:

```
var contents = from content in context.Contents
               join contenttype in context.ContentTypes on content.ContentTypeID equals contenttype.ContentTypeID
               select new { content, contenttype };
```

and then that gets put into a datagrid (not all of the data, only select columns such as content.ContentID etc).

The problem is that when I try and get the selected row, I cannot. I have the following code:

```
Console.WriteLine((Content)dataGrid1.SelectedItem);
```

which fails due to the fact that the type is both `Content` and `ContentType` - is there a way around this? The error I get is:

```
Unable to cast object of type '<>f__AnonymousType0`2[iAdvert_Desktop.Content,iAdvert_Desktop.ContentType]' to type 'iAdvert_Desktop.Content'.
```

If I just write the SelectedItem I get: `{ content = iAdvert_Desktop.Content, contenttype = iAdvert_Desktop.ContentType }` - is there a way I can do something like: `(Content)dataGrid1.SelectedItem['Content'];`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this post may answer your question:
[How do I get values from SelectedItem in ComboBox with Linq and C# 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1627360/how-do-i-get-values-from-selecteditem-in-combobox-with-linq-and-c-3-5)

Answer (score 1):

In WPF, you never need to use `SelectedItem`. You'd better redesign this so you use a collection view instead.

Comment: What are the reasons for this?

Comment: @Prisoner The reason is that the inherent way of working in WPF is using binding. And when you bind to a collection, you automatically bind to the current item, without explicitly calling `SelectedItem`. Here is one place where you can read about it: http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2007/09/03/bindtocurrent

Answer (score 1):

SelectedItem is not "both Content and ContentType", it's an anonymous type that has properties called Content and ContentType.

Why not spool up a little poco class that has the two properties you'd like and return one of those instead?

```
public class YourPocoClass
{
   public whateverContentIs Content { get; set; }
   public whateverContentTypeIs ContentType { get; set; }
}

var contents = from content in context.Contents
               join contenttype in context.ContentTypes on content.ContentTypeID equals contenttype.ContentTypeID
               select new YourPocoClass() {Content = content, ContentType = contenttype };


Console.WriteLine(((YourPocoClass)dataGrid1.SelectedItem).Content);
```

Comment: +1, thanks for the help but it came a bit too late and although your answer was very helpful I got my answer from Simen S's post. Thanks though!